# Xively graph showing incorrect x axis labels

Tags: xively

I'm using the Xively REST API to retrieve urls pointing to graphs covering various feed durations - https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/read/single_datastream/. The feeds records temperature and time.

I'm able to retrieve graphs for daily, weekly and yearly reports just fine:

***Daily url***
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/517809771/datastreams/Temperature.png?l=degrees%20celcius&b=true&g=true&start=2014-01-19T22:56:53+00:00&duration=1day

***Weekly url***
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/517809771/datastreams/Temperature.png?l=degrees%20celcius&b=true&g=true&start=2014-01-13T22:56:53+00:00&duration=7days

***Yearly url***
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/517809771/datastreams/Temperature.png?l=degrees%20celcius&b=true&g=true&start=2013-01-20T22:56:53+00:00&end=2014-01-20T22:56:53+00:00

However, the monthly report graphs appear to be using seconds since 1970 on the time (x) axis:

***Monthly url***
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/517809771/datastreams/Temperature.png?l=degrees%20celcius&b=true&g=true&start=2013-12-20T22:56:53+00:00&end=2014-01-20T22:56:53+00:00

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug in Xively's graph image rendering component... Anyhow, these days it's probably best to make graphs with [a bit of JavaScript](https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/channel-viz/) instead.

Comment: Blimey - you've killed two birds with one stone there. My next project is to be creating my own web page of graphs